# Firebase function snapshot.docs.maps is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting a CORS error as below but looking at the function log makes me think there is something wrong with my function. The function code is from a Udemy course im doing and not sure if any recent updates by google requires a different way to write the function.

Log error 1: snapshot.docs.maps is not a function

Log error 2: Unhandled rejection

[image]

[image]

[image]

Function code:

```
exports.reviewMLClassificationPredictions = functions.https.onRequest( async(request,response) => {


    await firestore.collection('classificationImages').where('viewed', '==', false).limit(5).get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Authorization, Content-Type, Accept");
        return response.send(snapshot.docs.maps((doc) => {
            let theObj = doc.data()
            theObj.firekey = doc.id
            theObj.feedback = {
                src: theObj.url,
                winner: theObj.winningLabel,
                saveUrl: 'to do...'
            }
            return theObj
        }))
    })
})
```

Comment: You have a typo.  It should be `snapshot.docs.map`.  It's not plural.

Comment: Also, you're working with kind of a poor code example.  One generally should not mix async/await with then.  Just use async/await.

Comment: oh silly me. spent 2 days trying to figure it out and it was a typo mistake. Sorry also how would we rewrite the async.await without then. Thanks Doug.